# capture the change in .xml file dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

is it possible to save the .xml file from the screen to main.xml?
 my requirement is to..                                                                    first i create a xml files with some files
 the user selects the required fields and select the save button. 
from next onwards the application directly show the user specified fields only
.                                                                                       directly by saving the selected field in the xml and remaining fields should be invisible the main.xml code is directly change to newly userspecified view....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)? From what I've read from your description I think it should cover your needs.

Comment: no i donot need to save data types. i need to save changed xml tags in already existed xml file

Comment: My answer went further - what if all the xml operations would be done by SharedPreferences? Saving, loading etc. You'd get autorefresh out of a box.